# Preserve HTML formatting in an XML node when converting to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have some long XML files which include HTML formatting within some of the nodes. For instance:

```
<note encodinganalog="isadg361 marc500">
    <p>Published, with some changes, as "In Small Townlands" in <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title> (1966).</p>
    <p>See also copy of "In Small Towlands" at reference <ref target="heaney.01.02.48" role="didid" actuate="onrequest">Heaney 1/2/48.</ref></p>
  </note>
```

Or:

```
<scopecontent encodinganalog="isadg331 marc520">
  <head>Scope and Content</head>
  <p>The Seamus Heaney Collection comprises typescript and manuscript poems, many of which were later pulished in <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title> and<title render="italic"> Door into the Dark</title>. There is also a short story titled<title render="italic"> The Blackberry Gatherers</title> and 8 letters to Philip Hobsbaum, including discussion of Heaney's work and The Group meetings in Belfast.</p>
</scopecontent>
```

Or:

```
<altformavail type="isadg342 marc530">
<head>Copies in Other Formats</head>
<p>Many of the poems were published, sometimes with changes, in <bibref><title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title> <imprint>(Faber, <date normal="1966">1966)</date></imprint></bibref> and <bibref><title render="italic">Door into the Dark</title> <imprint>(Faber, <date normal="1969">1969).</date></imprint></bibref></p>
  </altformavail>
```

In all of the examples I would like to keep everything that is mentioned (`<head>`, `<p>`, `<title>`, etc.) but when I use online tools such as http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm or import the XML into Excel as a data source, the tags within the nodes become column headers (e.g. in the `<note>` node `<title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title>` is split so that 'title' and 'render' become column headers with 'Death of a Naturalist' and 'italic' their values.

There is an XSLT already being applied to the XML in order to make some minor changes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- 1. identity template copies everything as is -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- 2. if there is an id attribute, delete it -->
<xsl:template match="unitid/@id" />

<!-- 3. move the value of the id attribute into the element value -->
<xsl:template match="unitid[@id]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="../@id | ../../@id" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- 4. create a <physloc> element inside <did> -->
<xsl:template match="did[not(physloc)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        <physloc><xsl:value-of select="unitid" /></physloc>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Could this XSLT be re-written to preserve the formatting for all the nodes so that when it is converted to CSV these tags are preserved?

Final Result:

```
    title, unitid, date, note, scopecontent, altformavail 
Death of a Naturalist , heaney.01.02.48 , 1966 , '<p>Published, with some changes, as "In Small Townlands" in <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title> (1966).</p>
    <p>See also copy of "In Small Towlands" at reference <ref target="heaney.01.02.48" role="didid" actuate="onrequest">Heaney 1/2/48.</ref></p>' , '<head>Scope and Content</head>
      <p>The Seamus Heaney Collection comprises typescript and manuscript poems, many of which were later pulished in <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title> and<title render="italic"> Door into the Dark</title>. There is also a short story titled<title render="italic"> The Blackberry Gatherers</title> and 8 letters to Philip Hobsbaum, including discussion of Heaney's work and The Group meetings in Belfast.</p>' , '<head>Copies in Other Formats</head>
    <p>Many of the poems were published, sometimes with changes, in <bibref><title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title> <imprint>(Faber, <date normal="1966">1966)</date></imprint></bibref> and <bibref><title render="italic">Door into the Dark</title> <imprint>(Faber, <date normal="1969">1969).</date></imprint></bibref></p>'
```

**Note:** it's not just the `<note>, <scopecontent> and <altformavail>` tags that has this level of formatting and it can apply to all the nodes within the XML.

Comment: If the text contains commas this would break csv format unless they are escaped. Are you doing that in your code?

Comment: Nope, escaping the commas within the content will also need to be added to the XSLT. Although when we convert it we can use other delimiters in the CSV e.g. pipe etc.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't use XSLT for CSV conversion? Why the intermediate XML?

Comment: @crizzis, to be honest, I didn't even think of doing it that way, I'm not very proficient when it comes to writing XSLT so I just thought to do the bare minimum. If it helps preserve the HTML formatting in the nodes, then I'm all for the CSV conversion taking place as part of the XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to produce the CSV itself using XSLT as this will give you greater control over the output.

Given the following input:

```
<elements>
    <element unitId="heaney.01.02.48">
        <title>Death of a Naturalist</title>
        <date>1966</date>
        <note encodinganalog="isadg361 marc500">
            <p>
                Published, with some changes, as "In Small Townlands" in
                <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title>
                (1966).
            </p>
            <p>
                See also copy of "In Small Towlands" at reference
                <ref target="heaney.01.02.48" role="didid" actuate="onrequest">Heaney
                    1/2/48.</ref>
            </p>
        </note>
        <scopecontent encodinganalog="isadg331 marc520">
            <head>Scope and Content</head>
            <p>
                The Seamus Heaney Collection comprises typescript and manuscript
                poems, many of which were later pulished in
                <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title>
                and
                <title render="italic"> Door into the Dark</title>
                . There is also a short story titled
                <title render="italic"> The Blackberry Gatherers</title>
                and 8 letters to Philip Hobsbaum, including discussion of Heaney's
                work and The Group meetings in Belfast.
            </p>
        </scopecontent>
        <altformavail type="isadg342 marc530">
            <head>Copies in Other Formats</head>
            <p>
                Many of the poems were published, sometimes with changes, in
                <bibref>
                    <title render="italic">Death of a Naturalist</title>
                    <imprint>
                        (Faber,
                        <date normal="1966">1966)</date>
                    </imprint>
                </bibref>
                and
                <bibref>
                    <title render="italic">Door into the Dark</title>
                    <imprint>
                        (Faber,
                        <date normal="1969">1969).</date>
                    </imprint>
                </bibref>
            </p>
        </altformavail>
    </element>
</elements>
```

You could use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>title,unitid,date,note,scopecontent,altformavail</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
            <!-- insert new line -->
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./title" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./@unitId" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./date" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./note" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./scopecontent" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="./altformavail" />
       </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title|date|note|scopecontent|altformavail">
        <!-- surround the contents with quotes -->
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces a CSV with the line breaks and multiple spaces preserved. If we want to normalize the spaces , we need to drill a little deeper into the original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>title,unitid,date,note,scopecontent,altformavail</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./title" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./@unitId" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./date" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./note" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./scopecontent" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./altformavail" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title|date|note|scopecontent|altformavail">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> <!-- We'll define additional processing rules for each node inside -->
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When an element is encountered... -->
    <xsl:template match="*"> 
        <!-- ...output an element with the same name... -->
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" >
            <!-- ...and attributes... -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*" />
            <!-- ...applying the rules for element and text nodes to whatever's inside -->
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When a text node is encountered, print its content with spaces normalized  -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <!-- If the node is empty, don't print anything -->
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space()">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(), ' ')" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need additional processing of the text content (e.g. escaping commas within the CSV columns), modify `concat(normalize-space(), ' ')` to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks for this, although using Saxon-HE 9.8.0.1N on Windows 10 brings up the following error:


`Transform -s:Argotist.xml -xsl:new-XSLT.xsl -o:redone.csv
Warning at xsl:stylesheet on line 2 column 54 of new-XSLT.xsl:
  Running an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 3.0 processor
Static error in xsl:output/@type on line 3 column 58 of new-XSLT.xsl:
  XTSE0090: Attribute @type is not allowed on element <xsl:output>
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation`

Comment: OK found the reason why, it should be `<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />` as `type` isn't a valid attribute, I've edited your answer accordingly. This time it more or less works, except the csv file produced at the end just has the column headers:                                                                            
eadid,titleproper,author,archdesc,corpname,subarea,unitid,unittitle,unitdate,extent,genreform,physfacet,persname,language,bioghist,scopecontent,arrangement,acqinfo,accruals,accessrestrict,userestrict,otherfindaid,relatedmaterial,bibliography

Comment: It might be because the structure of your input XML is a little different than the sample I've provided. Can you verify that the XSLT works with your processor and my sample? Note that `select="elements/element"` implies that `element` is a **direct child** of `elements`. Similarly, `./date`, `./note`, `./scopecontent` etc. only match if `date`, `note`, `scopecontent` are **direct children** of `element`. Perhaps if you posted a sample of the actual XML, I would be able to adjust the XSLT accordingly

Comment: that makes sense. The XML files themselves are generally thousands of lines long - this is a short one: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYjQWp?editors=1000. To match children would it be a case of something like `./did/unitid` where `did` is the parent?  The 2nd XSLT works better with the above sample than the 1st, however in the `note` node the comma after 'Published' isn't being escaped and so the rest of this node ends up under `scopeandcontent`.

Comment: `.` is the current node (the one matched by `for-each` in this case). `/` means 'child node' and `//` means 'descendant node (at any depth)'. I've [adjusted the XSLT](https://pastebin.com/tkWP6TDZ) a bit to the new sample to give you an idea on how to match the rest of the fields. I've also changed the delimiter to a pipe (there's no viable way to escape a comma in a text file)

Comment: thanks for this. I've think I've mostly got what I need and I've made changes to fit our horrible XML files. I've also added some extra templates to preserve some of the HTML tags e.g `<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:text>&lt;p&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/><xsl:text>&lt;\p&gt;</xsl:text></xsl:template>`